# how can i do a javascript code combine auto slider with manual slider?

Tags: javascript, html, slider

i search for someone to help me combine auto slide with a manual slide 
,for now i'am just doing the the auto silde or the manual slide , but i don't have any idea about how can i combine it ,here i'am just doing auto auto slide.

```
var element=document.getElementById("slider");
var myImgs = [ 
    "../banner4.jpg",
    "../bannerdc.jpg",
    "../bannerknot.jpg",
    "../mr7banner.jpg",
    "../kornbanner.jpg"
];
function mySlide(element, myImgs){

    setInterval(function(){
    var Random = Math.floor(Math.random()*myImgs.length);
    element.src=myImgs[Random];
     },3000);
}

mySlide(element, myImgs);
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code so that we can reproduce your issue and provide you with a functioning answer. Edit your question and add the accompanying HTML and CSS (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Save the SetInterval variable so you can clear the timeout later, then use event's to handle the "manual slider".

Example code:

```
var interval;
var element=document.getElementById("slider");
var myImgs = [ 
    "../banner4.jpg",
    "../bannerdc.jpg",
    "../bannerknot.jpg",
    "../mr7banner.jpg",
    "../kornbanner.jpg"
];
function mySlide(element, myImgs){

    interval=setInterval(function(){
    var Random = Math.floor(Math.random()*myImgs.length);
    element.src=myImgs[Random];
     },3000);
}

mySlide(element, myImgs);
//a button you create for manual changing the slider
$("#arrow-right").click(function(){
    clearInterval(interval) //Stop the "auto slider"
    var index=myImgs.indexOf(element.src);
    element.src=myImgs[index+1];
    mySlide(element, myImgs); //Restart the "auto slider" can also do this in another button
})
//a button you create for manual changing the slider
$("#arrow-left").click(function(){
    clearInterval(interval) //Stop the "auto slider"
    var index=myImgs.indexOf(element.src);
    element.src=myImgs[index-1];
    mySlide(element, myImgs); //Restart the "auto slider" can also do this in another button
})
```

**NOTE:** Do note you should also test the limit conditions - when you're on the last image and try to go right, and when you're on the left image and try to go left!

Something like:

```
//For right
if(index==myImgs.length-1)
  element.src=myImgs[0];
//For left
if(index==0)
  element.src=myImgs[myImgs.length-1];
```